$X+Y$ is closed iff $\inf\{||x-y||: ||x||=1, y \in Y\} > 0$

Prove that $X+Y$ is closed, where $X$ and $Y$ are closed normed subspaces of $Z$ and $X \cap Y = \{0\},$ iff $\inf\{||x-y||: ||x||=1, y \in Y\} > 0.$

This question looks easy but has me stumped for several hours. For the forward direction, I assume otherwise, and there exists $x_\varepsilon$ with $||x_{\varepsilon}||=1$ and $y_{\varepsilon}\in Y$ and $||x_{\varepsilon}-y_{\varepsilon}|| \leq \varepsilon$, right?
But how do I use that to get a contradiction? I was thinking of letting $x_n+y_n \rightarrow x_{\varepsilon}+y_{\varepsilon}$ but not sure where to continue from there.
Thank you so much.

You probably also want the condition that $X\cap Y={0}$.

@Sangchul Lee, I just edited the question, thanks!

"Closed" here presumably means closed in some ambient space, which we probably also want to assume is complete.

@user469053 fixed!

Do you mean $\inf{\ldots}>0$?

@SangchulLee yes, so sorry about the typos.

For a Banach space $A$, we let $$S_A=\{a\in A:\|a\|=1\}.$$  For two subsets $C,D$ of a Banach space $A$, $$d(B,C)=\inf\{\|b-c\|:b\in B,c\in C\}.$$
Assume $X,Y$ are closed subspaces of $Z$ and $X\cap Y=\{0\}$ (the statement can be false without trivial intersection).

Claim: $d(S_X,Y)>0$ iff $d(S_X,S_Y)>0$ iff $d(X,S_Y)>0$.

Proof of Claim: Of course, $d(S_X,S_Y)\geqslant d(S_X,Y)$, since $S_Y\subset Y$. If $d(S_X,Y)=0$, then for any $0<\varepsilon<1$, we can choose $x\in S_X$ and $y\in Y$ such that $\|x-y\|<\varepsilon/2$. Let $u=y/\|y\|$, so $y=\|y\|u$. Then \begin{align*} \|x-u\| & \leqslant \Bigl\|x-y\Bigr\|+\Bigl\|y-u\Bigr\| =\Bigl\|x-y\Bigr\|+\Bigl\|\|y\|u-u\Bigr\| \\ & <\varepsilon/2+\Bigl|\|y\|-1\Bigr|\|u\| \leqslant \varepsilon/2+\|y-x\|<\varepsilon. \end{align*} Since we can do this for any $\varepsilon>0$, $d(S_X,S_Y)=0$. So $d(S_X,Y)=0$ iff $d(S_X,S_Y)=0$. By symmetry, $d(S_X,S_Y)=0$ iff $d(X,S_Y)=0$. $\blacksquare$
Let $X\oplus Y$ be the Banach space consisting of all pairs $\{(x,y):x\in X,y\in Y\}$ endowed with the norm $\|(x,y)\|_1=\|x\|+\|y\|$.  Define $$T:X\oplus_1 Y\to Z$$ by $$T(x,y)=x-y.$$  Of course, $T$ is linear. Note also that $$\|x+y\|\leqslant \|x\|+\|y\|=\|(x,y)\|_1,$$ so $T$ is continuous. Note also that $(x,y)\in \ker(T)$ iff $x-y=0$ iff $x=y$. But this happens iff $x=y=0$. So $T$ is an injection.
Note that the range of $T$ is $X+Y$, so
$$X+Y=T(X\oplus_1 Y)\text{ is closed iff }T\text{ is closed range.}\tag{$1$}$$
Since $T$ is a continuous, linear injection, by the open mapping theorem, $$T\text{ is closed range iff } \inf \{\|Tu\|:u\in S_{X\oplus_1 Y}\}>0.\tag{$2$}$$
Note also that $$\inf\{\|Tu\|:u\in S_{X\oplus_1 Y}\}>0 \text{ iff }d(S_X,Y)>0.\tag{$3$}$$
To see $(3)$, assume $d(S_X,Y)>0$. By our claim, this implies that $d(X,S_Y)>0$. Let $d=\min\{d(S_X,Y),d(X,S_Y)\}>0$.   Then for any $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, if $\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}=0$, then $x=y=0$ and $$\|T(x,y)\|=0=d\cdot [\|x\|+\|y\|].$$ If $\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}>0$, first suppose that $\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}=\|x\|$. Then let $x'=x/\|x\|$ and $y'=y/\|x\|$. Then $$\|T(x',y')\|=\|x'-y'\|\geqslant d(S_X,Y)\geqslant d.$$  Then $$\|T(x,y)\|=\|x\|\|T(x',y')\|\geqslant d\|x\|=d\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}\geqslant (d/2)[\|x\|+\|y\|].$$  If $\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}=\|y\|$, by symmetry, by a similar argument diving through by $\|y\|$ instead of $\|x\|$, we obtain $$\|T(x,y)\|\geqslant (d/2)[\|x\|+\|y\|].$$ Therefore if $d(S_X,Y)>0$ then there exists $c>0$ (we can take $c=\min\{d(S_X,Y),d(X,S_Y)\}/2$) such that $\|T(x,y)\|\geqslant c[\|x\|+\|y\|]$.
On the other hand, if there exists $c>0$ such that $\|T(x,y)\|\geqslant c[\|x\|+\|y\|]$, then for any $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=1$ and any $y\in Y$, $$\|x-y\|=\|T(x,y)\|\geqslant c[\|x\|+\|y\|]\geqslant c[1+0]=c.$$ Therefore $d(S_X,Y)\geqslant c>0$.
Last, $(1)\Leftrightarrow (2)\Leftrightarrow(3)$ gives the result.

Thank you, the proof is way more involved than I expected!

It's possible that the open mapping theorem is a sledgehammer here. There could be a nicer proof if we inspect the guts of the open mapping theorem and try to isolate the necessary piece(s).
